# How to create column cells, where each cell contains matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a function in Matlab that requires as the input

> column cells, where each cell contains an SPD matrix

To be more precise this function requires 3 input arguments, the first two are column cells, where each cell contains an SPD matrix, But I don't know how to define a column cell in Matlab. I have tried this:

```
TestData(:,:,12) = T;
```

TestData is supposed to be my cell column and `T` is a matrix that should be in this column. for every matrix that I have, I put it in a variable called `T` and then using above command I add it to a 3D array. So the first matrix is in `TestData(:,:,1)`, The second one is in `TestData(:,:,1)` and so on. When I run my function with `TestData` as the input variable i get this error:

> Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

So I think I didn't define a cell column right.

Comment: That's not a cell, it's a 3D array like you said. You likely want `num2cell(TestData, 3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 3D array is *not* a cell. If you want each 3D slice of your 3D array to be a separate cell element, you could use `num2cell` followed by a call to `squeeze` to remove all singleton dimensions and make it an `N x 1` cell array.

```
inputs = squeeze(num2cell(TestData, [1 2]));
```